# Drawing Architectural Diagrams Before Building Software

Tags: software-development, development-process

I don't know I am posting this question. in the right place. I thought I could post it on stackoverflow but this places looks more suitable for this question.

I am wondering that how much drawing a a blueprint/sketch of **the architecture of a project** before starting to actually build it would help? could it be useful? what are your experiences on this. I am about to dive into a big project on my firm and I just wanna explore the options before getting into it.

Also, is there some online tools which are specifically designed for that kind of purposes so that I can do this kind of stuff on my machine instead of on a paper.

Comment: are you asking about visual design? How the various components integrate with each other? use cases? or what?

Comment: What is "blueprint sketch of a project"?

Comment: @tugberk: A project consists of a lot of aspects. If you don't say, no one will know what your target is (budget planning, time plan,resource..)

Comment: @Hoang there won't be much programmer working on the project. just two. we will be using .net 4, web forms and mvc together, ms sql, windows server 2008 r2 and iis 7.

Comment: It seems like your question is related to drawing architectural design diagrams. Is that correct?

Comment: @ashes999 that's perfectly correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have much experience with this in terms of tools. I find architectural diagrams really useful, especially with complex interactions and multiple systems.

I had one project that required JQuery, Silverlight, and PHP all rolled together. I stuck to pen and paper and drew up some interaction diagrams (UML is really useful for cases like this) to make sure I understood the workflow.

Hence, I would say stick to pen and paper if you can. Google Docs has some online drawing functionality, if you're interested in having it available online.

Comment: @ashes9999 thanks for the answer. I'll stick to the pen if I will have to use google docs for that. do you mean this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language by UML?

Comment: @tugberk ok, whatever works for you! UML is big, scary, and sometimes ugly; I would stick to it for class diagrams, and process flow diagrams (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Sequenz_diagramm-1.png).

Comment: @ashes9999 I will start with the pen and paper and let's see how long it lasts :) thanks for the answer again.

Answer (score 1):

Since I started out as an AutoCAD drafter for architectural firms designing buildings, I am a big fan of software architectural diagrams because I tend to be a graphically oriented person. However, not everyone agrees with me on that. This seems like another "6 month" type of question - draw whatever information **now** that you think will be critical 6 months into the future.

When it comes to tools, I can get a lot of mileage out of Visio but I am really comfortable with the software. You can do really good diagrams with Balsamiq Mockups that have a rough look-and-feel that offer the right image for an early project.